# PHP Templated site w/ file_get_content links

Tags: php, html, xhtml, hyperlink

Ok so i have a template  script my friend built for me. I'll include all file names.

OK so what is not working is file_get_contents is not grabing the content

(1 I don't know where the content should be placed.

(2 I want it placed in a directory so that IF i change the template the area where content stays is the same.

(3 I'm trying to get file_get_contents to load the links ?=about ?=services etc into to body.tpl in the contents div i have specified with #CONTENTS#

(4 The Dir Tree is as follows

```
 htdocs>
    classes> file.class.php
    contents> where i want #CONTENTS# (file_get_contents) to grab data from
    images> content (changing images)
    templates> where the templates are hosted
            clean>main template (Files are header.tpl, body.tpl, footer.tpl, styles.css, menu_style.css, and the images folder for images relating to the template itself.)
            other templates>(to come)
```

please any help is appreciated.  whats the issues is now the script is putting everything in the correct area loading it just not displaying it?.

/* file.class.php */

```
<?php

$file = new file();

class file{
    var $path = "templates/clean";
    var $ext = "tpl";

    function loadfile($filename){
  return file_get_contents($this->path . "/" . $filename . "." . $this->ext);
 }

 function setcontent($content,$newcontent,$vartoreplace='#CONTENT#'){
  $val = str_replace($vartoreplace,$newcontent,$content);
  return $val;
 }

 function p($content) {
  $v = $content;
  $v = str_replace('#CONTENT#','',$v);
  print $v;
 }
}
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    // if not, lets load our index page(you can change home.php to whatever you want:
    ob_start();
    include("contents/".'main.php');
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    // else $_GET['page'] was set so lets do stuff:
    } else {
    // lets first check if the file exists:
    if(file_exists($_GET['page'].'.php')){
    // and lets include that then:
    ob_start();
    include("contents/". $_GET['page'] . '.php');
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();


    // sorry mate, could not find it:
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, could not find <strong>' . $_GET['page'] .'.php</strong>';
    }
}
?>
```

if some one could trim that down so it JUST  is the template required code and file get contents.

/* index.php */

```
<?php
    include('classes/file.class.php');

    // load the templates
    $header = $file->loadfile('header');
    $body = $file->loadfile('body');
    $footer = $file->loadfile('footer');

    // fill body.tpl #CONTENT# slot with $content
    $body = $file->setcontent($body, $content);

    // cleanup and output the full page
    $file->p($header . $body . $footer);

?>
```

/* header.tpl */

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow"/>
<meta name="distribution" content="global"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<link href="templates/clean/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/clean/menu_style.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div id="logo"><a href="index.php" style="height:30px;width:150px;"><img src="images/logo.png" border="0" alt=""/></a></div>
   <div id="menuo"> 
    <div class="menu">
     <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="?page=home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="?page=about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="?page=services">Services</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="?page=instore">InStore Repairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=inhome">InHome Repairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=website">Website Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=soon">Comming Soon.</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
      <li><a href="?page=products">Products</a>
                   <ul>
                   <li><a href="?page=pchard">Computer Hardware</a></li>
                   <li><a href="?page=monitor">Monitor's</a></li>
                   <li><a href="?page=laptop">Laptop + Netbooks</a></li>
                   <li><a href="?page=soon">Comming Soon.</a></li>
                   </ul>
             </li>
      <li><a href="?page=contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id="headerf">
 </div>
```

/* body.tpl */

```
   <div id="bodys">
    <div id="bodt"></div>
        <div id="bodm">
            <div id="contents">
                #CONTENT#
                </div>
    <div id="bodb"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

/* footer.tpl */

```
<div id="footer">
<div style="position:absolute; top:4px; left:4px;"><img src="images/ff.png" alt="ok"></div> <div style="position:absolute; top:4px; right:5px; color:#FFFFFF;">&copy;2010 <a href="mailto:">Company Name</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so i KNOW it's not a css/html issue now well AT LEAST not html i ran validator.w3.org passed with flying colors the site in-question in-case anyone needs to look at it IS designed.sytes.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, your content is inside *about.php* (for instance).

this file is in the "contents" directory : contents/about.php

the command

```
include('about.php')
```

will load and execute the script *about.php* inline. So it will print its content exactly where the *include* call is done. What you see must look like :

```
(content of about.php) | header | body | footer
```

If you want $content to have the correct value, change the line

```
include($_GET['page'].'.php');
```

with

```
ob_start();
include("contents/". $_GET['page'] . '.php');
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

this will use the object buffering technique to make PHP understand that it should not render the content of the file inline, but put it in the $content variable instead.

I Hope this helps !

Comment: I tried doing what you said and it doesn't change a thing. i tried both updated it in op

Comment: I modified the snipped to take into account the fact that "about.php" is in "contents/about.php". Tell me if it work.

Please do not keep the "exploded" version ob_start/ob_end_clean. you need to have

ob_start();
INCLUDE(.....)
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

around each include. I'll clarify if this is not clear.

If this does not work, can you elaborate on 

1/ what is the URL that you are calling in your browser ?
2/ what you are seeing ?

Jerome

Comment: genius! thanks alot that worked great the contents is where it should be now (found out because it was looking for contents/main.php and it was not there so it showed not found jargon until i put it in the folder to bad a new issue appears to risen  where the content doesn't display though. I've updated my code to show what i have done

Comment: the site if you would like to see is http://designed.sytes.net/index.php this is just the development address

Comment: i've made a .phps for both index.php and file.class.php

Answer (score 1):

the template script that your friend built for you is filled with helper functions that will help you with templating your site.

currently, I think you have 2 problems :

1. the location of the templates
2. using the template mechanism

## 1. the location of the templates

Currently, your friend's script states

```
var $path = "templates/clean";
```

which means that you should create a *templates* folder and a *templates/clean* folder in the directory where you have put *index.php* and put your templates (header.tpl, body.tpl, footer.tpl) inside.

## 2. using the template mechanism

Try using

```
<?php
    include('classes/file.class.php');

    // load the templates
    $header = $file->loadfile('header');
    $body = $file->loadfile('body');
    $footer = $file->loadfile('footer');

    // fill body.tpl #CONTENT# slot with "Hello World!"
    $body = $file->setcontent($body, "Hello World!");

    // cleanup and output the full page
    $file->p($header . $body . $footer);

?>
```

The setcontent find the occurence of #CONTENT# in the pre-loaded body.tpl and replaces it with a specific content (in this case, "Hello World")

I hope this will put you on good track ! tell me if it works.
Jerome

Comment: ok SO what did was added "$body = $file->setcontent($body, $content);" like you said but changed "Hello World!" to "$content" so it reads that tag and it works it goes to read using
"if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
 $content = $_GET['page'].'.php'; 
} else {
 $content = 'main.php';
}"
so when i click about and the script reads <a href="page?=about" it loads the content into the correct div in the body.tpl BUT it just shows about.php not the actual content any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be on the line

```
if(file_exists($_GET['page'].'.php')){
```

It should read

```
if(file_exists('contents/'.$_GET['page'].'.php')){
```

Hope this helps